# Recoverable schedule in database

Tags: database, schedule

```
R1(A) // The read of object A returns 100       
W1(A)   // The write adds 50 to the value and we get 150        
W2(A)   // Do a dirty write of 200
Commit T2   
R3(A) // Read new value of A returns 200
W3(A) // Add 50 to the value to get 250
Commit T3
Commit T1
```

I am a bit confused about this one scenario, if I replace the Commit of T1
with an Abort instead, is the operation of R3(A) going to be 200 or 100? Since the operation W2(A) does not even care about the value of A that results from T1 is it still affected?

EDIT:
For more clarification, I have three transactions, I call them T1, T2, T3. Each transaction can do a (R)ead and a (W)rite of some data from and to disk where the database is. I am mainly asking about this question in relation to cascading aborts if that is the correct term. The transactions also occur from top to bottom of increasing time in order.

Comment: We have no idea what you're describing. Please post more context.

Comment: @Dai I have added some context to it as per request, please let me know if that is to your satisfaction. I also realize that it wasn't specific enough so I apologize.